# Upload Android app to Fabric using fastlane display this error "Error fetching remote file: Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect"

Tags: android, ssl, crashlytics, google-fabric, fastlane

Im setting up a new machine to run Android pipeline, when I'm trying to upload APK to Fabric using fastlane display this error: Fastlane finished with errors

[!] Error fetching remote file: Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect

I have proxy, I already set the proxy in bash_profile, gradle.proprieties, etc/profile

Result:

```
[11:47:10]: The `generated_fastfile_id` action was deprecated, you can remove the line from your `Fastfile`
[11:47:10]: ------------------------------
[11:47:10]: --- Step: default_platform ---
[11:47:10]: ------------------------------
[11:47:10]: Driving the lane 'beta_deploy' 
[11:47:10]: -----------------------------------------------
[11:47:10]: --- Step: Switch to upload_crashlytics lane ---
[11:47:10]: -----------------------------------------------
[11:47:10]: Cruising over to lane 'upload_crashlytics' 
[11:47:10]: -------------------------
[11:47:10]: --- Step: crashlytics ---
[11:47:10]: -------------------------
[11:47:10]: Downloading Crashlytics Support Library - this might take a minute...

+------------------+-------------+
|          Lane Context          |
+------------------+-------------+
| DEFAULT_PLATFORM | android     |
| PLATFORM_NAME    |             |
| LANE_NAME        | beta_deploy |
+------------------+-------------+

[11:47:10]: Error fetching remote file: Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect

+------+-----------------------------------+-------------+
|                    fastlane summary                    |
+------+-----------------------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action                            | Time (in s) |
+------+-----------------------------------+-------------+
| 1    | Verifying fastlane version        | 0           |
| 2    | default_platform                  | 0           |
| 3    | Switch to upload_crashlytics lane | 0           |
|    | crashlytics                       | 0           |
+------+-----------------------------------+-------------+

[11:47:10]: fastlane finished with errors

[!] Error fetching remote file: Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect
)
```

Upload to Fabric is display error, I expected without errors.

Comment: Can you show us the "beta_deploy" lane?

Comment: Did this get resolved? Can you confirm that the upload works if you don't use the proxy?